# How to automate online tasks in linux?

Tags: automation, web

I want to automate some of my online tasks like, checking my ticket status, login to a website and folow some links and get some info, pay my bills, recharge my mobile etc,.

I am looking for something similar to [imacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) but I should be able to set a cron job to do this and may be a lightweight virtual browser designed for such automation.

Is there any opensource tools that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Shellscript + Curl is a way but not the easyest.